# Nested classes and tags

Tags: css

I know its basic, I know it's being asked, I just don't know the right *term* for it, and can't look for it on Google .

I would like to nest a `tag` inside a CSS `class` :

```
.fullPageGallery
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

    >h1
    // some properties of h1 here (h1 is a tag inside this class)

    .AnotherClass
    //some properties of another class here (a div inside this class)
}
```

Comment: Definitely a dupe here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it in pure CSS - use [SCSS/SASS](https://sass-lang.com) or [Less](http://lesscss.org):

(The below should work for both of the above languages):

```
.fullPageGallery {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    h1 { /* Properties */ }
    .AnotherClass { /* Properties */ }
}
```

Comment: do i need to include some file/framework in order to use this ? or just write it like that ?

Comment: You'd need to include the scripts from the websites - it's an external plugin.

Comment: please don't add less/sass tag to the question. It doesn't make sense and it changes completely  the meaning of the question. The OP is asking about a CSS way and he's not aware about SASS/LESS

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it using vanilla CSS. You can, however, use Less or Sass (SCSS) which are CSS Preprocessors, and support selector nesting like you desire.

They get compiled to standard CSS via a build process.

Read more about Sass [here](https://sass-lang.com/) and about Less [here](http://lesscss.org/).